# How can I include a report (not a dashboard) on a page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, reports-api, custom-reports

I need to include a report in a lightning page.
I can add the report in a Report Chart, but I want only show the report, no charts. I would like do it by standard, but I can developer a lightning component or a visualForce

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create dashboard --> display as --> lightning table

[image]

Comment: This loses any conditional formatting in your table.